# Question on Electricity (A-level)

Tags: resistivity

A cell connected to two resistors P and Q that are connected in parallel. The resistors are metal wires made of the same material. The length of P is L and the length of Q is 2L. The diameter of P is d/2 and the diameter of Q is d. The current through P is I1 and the current through Q is I2.
What is the ratio I1/ I2?

I tried to express the resistance through the resistivity formula and then divide one by the another to get the current ratio.
But an answer supposed to be D (ratio equal 8), and not 1/2.
Would appreciate any tip[image]
[image]

Comment: What you have dis wod divided R2/R1. And that's why you got 1/2.  Amdnm to get answer D. You need to have P length equal 2L and Q length L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is just wrong, and none of the choices is correct. I get the same 1/2 you do. P has 4x the resistance per length, and half the length, so P has 2x the resistance, and 1/2 the current.

If they had said "the diameter of P is d and the diameter of Q is d/2" then 8 would be a correct answer.